# Show/Hide div based on select box

Tags: jquery, html

There are a number of answers on here about this, and I've tried to modify them to suit but it's not working.

I've made a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/DrPz4/

Select box code:

```
<div class="options">
    <h2>Available Options</h2>
    <br />
    <div id="option-230" class="option">
        <span class="required">*</span>
        <b>Size:</b><br />
        <select name="option[230]">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="28">Size 10                        </option>
            <option value="29">Size 12                        </option>
            <option value="30">Size 14                        </option>
            <option value="32">Size 16                        </option>
            <option value="31">Size 18                        </option>
            <option value="117">Made to Measure                        </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="option-253" class="option">
        <b>Bust (cm):</b><br />
        <input type="text" name="option[253]" value="" class="input-text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="option-254" class="option">
        <b>Waist (cm):</b><br />
        <input type="text" name="option[254]" value="" class="input-text" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="option-255" class="option">
        <b>Hips (cm):</b><br />
        <input type="text" name="option[255]" value="" class="input-text" />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var MTM = jQuery('#option[230]');
var select = this.value;
MTM.change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '117') {
        $('#option-253').show();
        }
    else $('#option-253').hide();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? What's your question? Don't just dump code here and expect us to figure out what your issue is.

Comment: `var MTM = jQuery('[name="option[230]"]');` is your problem, fix the selector. http://jsfiddle.net/r7FvF/

Comment: @j08691 sorry, i'm only new here and last time I asked a question all of the explanation got edited out so just the code was left.. I thought that was how I was meant to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. The selector you used `#option[230]` will select an element with id `option` and attribute `230` like `<select id="option" 230>..</select>`.

In this case you can use the `name` of the `select` element as the selector as given below...

```
var MTM = jQuery('select[name="option[230]"]');
MTM.change(function () {
    $('#option-253').toggle(this.value == 117);
    $('#option-254').toggle(this.value == 117);
    $('#option-255').toggle(this.value == 117);
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ftUwZ/)

Comment: Thank you, that's almost perfect! The only problem is now, that the divs are shown on page load. Once you select an option in the dropdown they disappear, but I need them to be hidden on load. I'm trying to do display:none with CSS but it's having no effect. Is the JS overriding it?

Comment: that worked perfectly! What I'm trying to do now is modify it to be more generic (because the selector changes for each product, as does the "117" value). I've made a new fiddle to try and figure it out, but this.html and this.innerhtml don't seem to be working. Would you mind having a look at it please? http://jsfiddle.net/e6hG5/3/

Answer (score 2):

**You are trying to select without id in jquery**

First of all define `Id` on select control like as below

```
 <select name="option[230]" id="option--230">
```

And use as below:

```
jQuery('#option--230').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '117') {
        $('#option-253').show();
        }
    else $('#option-253').hide();
});
```

then use as

```
jQuery('select[name="option[230]"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '117') {
        $('#option-253').show();
        }
    else $('#option-253').hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrPz4/9/)

Comment: thx for the quick reply. The names and IDs are generated by the software creating the code (opencart), so I have to use what it produces in my script.